# How to disable/enable custom click event for an img element in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an ASP.NET datepicker control (no source available ) which produces an image element, which when clicked shows a calendar. I want to disable or enable on demand the image through JavaScript. When I added the 'disabled' attribute to the img element, some script in the page always goes in a busy state and the page never finishes rendering. My guess the disabled attribute is causing a conflict in some way.

My next attempt now is to disable the custom click event which the ASP.NET control adds unoptrusively. How do I disable the click event? How do I re-enable it so that the img works back as normal. I am also using jQuery 1.4.

Comment: when you tried to disable the <img /> was if after document ready?

Comment: Yes. I have a checkbox which enables/disables the img.

Answer (score 0):

```
var $img = $('img#yourid'),
    handler = $img.get(0).onclick; // previous click handler
// unbind
$img.unbind('click').click(function(){
    alert('new click');
});
// rebind
$img.unbind('click').click(handler);
```

You might need to check other events also (mousedown mouseup etc).

Answer (score 0):

I have an example here, which swaps all of the click events to a hidden div, and then back again to re-enable:

http://jsfiddle.net/Jbs9V/

There might be some shortcuts to do this, but this works.  Likewise, you could store the click handlers in a global var and load them from that:

http://jsfiddle.net/8ZKJR/

Answer (score 0):

I think that the bug could be happen because the datepicker uses the text control to do its stuff, but if the control is disabled, datepicker cannot continue, but you can use other attribute to do almost the same thing, use the attribute readonly in your tag:

`readonly="readonly"`

you can use the attribute readonly in your html input.

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [unbind()](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) to remove any custom event handler using jquery.